# UI is not updated instantly iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, multithreading, user-interface, swift

my code looks like this:

```
var images = [UIImage]()
var isFirstLoop = true
for (imageID in self.imageID’s)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORIT Y_DEFAULT, 0), {
        let imageToAdd = self.getImageFromUrlByID(imageID)
        if isFirstLoop
        {
            self.addSubView(imageToAdd)
            isFirstLoop = false
        }
    }
}
```

I'm just can't figure why the first image is added as subView just when all the tasks are finished.... I tried to wrap addSubView with any possible combination of dispatch_async with main thread and so on... 
it take ages until the image is added as subView.. please help me :)
Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: Could you post your attempt at running the addSubview() call on the main thread?

Comment: Try this
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Your code here
    });

Comment: in all the cases, the UIImageView is added to the UI, I know it because if I made it with tapGestureRecognizer which prints added, but the image itself is not appear until everything is ended, it just there as transparent UIImageView.. what should I do??

Comment: Are you sure `imageToAdd` is a `UIImageView` and not a `UIImage`?

Answer (score 3):

***ALWAYS*** update the UI from the main thread.

Comment: in all the cases, the UIImageView is added to the UI, I know it because if I made it with tapGestureRecognizer which prints added, but the image itself is not appear until everything is ended, it just there as transparent UIImageView.. what should I do??

Comment: Where are you printing "added"? If it's to the log, that doesn't necessarily mean you added it on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Only include the `dispatch_get_main_queue` where you actually update the UI. If your method `getImageFromURLByID()` accesses the internet, which I assume it does, you don't want anything with a connection on the UI thread because it will often freeze it up.

```
for imageID in imageIDs
{
    let imageToAdd = self.getImageFromUrlByID(imageID)

    if isFirstLoop {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() {
            var imageView = UIImageView(image: imageToAdd)
            imageView.frame = someFrame
            self.addSubView(imageView)
        }
        isFirstLoop = false
    }
}
```

Comment: in all the cases, the UIImageView is added to the UI, I know it because if I made it with tapGestureRecognizer which prints added, but the image itself is not appear until everything is ended, it just there as transparent UIImageView.. what should I do??

Comment: You can't just add a UIImage as a subview. It has to be housed in a UIImageView. The updated code creates many UIImageViews, but you can also just create one as a class variable and set its image using `self.imageView.image = imageToAdd`

Comment: it's not the issue... the code written above is a simplified version of my code which I wrote in a note and not in Xcode so I forgot to add the UIImageView.. my code is running, the UIImageView is added to the main view, but the image which is inside it, is not shown until all the tasks are being completed, even if I use dispatch_get_main_queue()